# response.text is not a function error when using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a JavaScript code to return data from a API request to the user when they click a button, this is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    response = fetch(URL, { mode:'no-cors',});
    alert(response.text())
}
```

but that returns an error: `response.text is not a function` how can I turn `response = fetch(URL, { mode:'no-cors',});` into text?

Comment: `fetch(...).then(response => alert(response.text())`

Comment: There's no `await` in your function, you can't be getting that error.